# excel dictionary object error

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary

I have an application for which I am currently using a dictionary object (specifically, it's a dictionary of dictionaries of dictionaries, so each lookup has three steps, if that makes any sense!). I do a large number of lookups on these dictionaries and multiply the results together.

The problem is that in the previous version of the application, I used the VLookup function to accomplish this functionality, and it would error out when I would try to look up a key that didn't exist. Now, it returns a "Empty", which Excel is happy to multiply by whatever I already had and return a zero. This is hard to track, and I'd very much prefer for it to return an error like before.

**Is there something I can change to get it to return the error like it would with a VLookup, or do I need to create a new class module to do this?** A class module would likely require me to re-write a large amount of code, which I'd like to avoid (there are hundreds of lookups I would have to update in the code).

Thanks.

Here is some of my code:

This is the module I use to load in all the tables to the dictionary:

```
Sub LoadFactorsAndBaseRates()
    Dim t As Double
    t = Timer
    Dim n As Name
    Dim TempArray()
    Dim dict1 As Dictionary
    Dim dict2 As Dictionary
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    For Each n In ThisWorkbook.Names
        If InStr(1, n.RefersTo, "#") <> 0 Or InStr(1, n.RefersTo, "\") Then GoTo skipname
        If Not FactorLookup.Exists(n.Name) And n.RefersToRange.Parent.Name <> "Rate Matrix" And InStr(1, n.Name, "Print") = 0 And InStr(1, n.Name, "FilterDatabase") = 0 And n.Name <> "Policies" Then
            Set dict1 = New Dictionary
            On Error GoTo err1
            TempArray = n.RefersToRange.Value
            For j = 1 To n.RefersToRange.Columns.Count
                On Error Resume Next
                Set dict2 = New Dictionary
                For i = 1 To UBound(TempArray, 1)
                    dict2.Add TempArray(i, 1), TempArray(i, j)
                Next i
                dict1.Add j, dict2
            Next j
            Erase TempArray
            FactorLookup.Add n.Name, dict1
        End If
skipname:
    Next n
    Exit Sub
err1:
    If Err.number = 1004 Then Resume skipname
End Sub
```

And here is a sample of the lookup code:

```
CoverageColumn = 2
'Base Rate
        Temp = FactorLookup("Base_Rates")(CoverageColumn)(State & "_" & Company & "_" & Terr)

If Vehicle <> "Snowmobile" Then
'Class 1
    x = FactorLookup("Class1")(CoverageColumn)(State & "_" & Company & "_" & Class1)
    Temp = xRound(Temp * x, 1)
'Class 2
    x = FactorLookup("Class2")(CoverageColumn)(State & "_" & Company & "_" & Class2)
    Temp = xRound(Temp * x, 1)
'Class 3
    x = FactorLookup("Class3")(CoverageColumn)(State & "_" & Company & "_" & Class3)
    Temp = xRound(Temp * x, 1)
'Class 4
    x = FactorLookup("Class4")(CoverageColumn)(State & "_" & Company & "_" & Class4)
    Temp = xRound(Temp * x, 1)
```

The code is basically just a bunch of pages of this: look up, multiply, round to the nearest tenth, repeat. Occasionally, there's a step where we add instead of multiplying.

The xRound function adds 0.0000001 and then uses the Round function to round to the indicated number of decimal places (to account for the weirdness of the Excel VBA round function).

Comment: Can you check the data to see if it's empty prior to the multiplication? E.g. `If IsEmpty(MyVariable) = False then ...`

Comment: Before we get any further, I'm curious why you have three levels of nested dictionary. I assume you're using them to build relationships between tables, then query those relationships. In that case, I'd definitely suggest moving to a system built for these sorts of queries (either migrating to a database or just querying Excel directly like a database using ADO).

Comment: Yes, the data is empty prior to the multiplication, but adding "if" statements around every single lookup would be extremely time-consuming. I can do it, but it's something I'm trying to avoid if possible.

Comment: I have three levels to replace the VLookup structure I had previously. Basically, I have a bunch of named ranges in the workbook. The VBA looks up numbers in each one of them. Instead of VLookup(key, range, column, FALSE), I now have DictionaryLookup(range)(column)(key). There are no relationships between the tables (i. e. no join-type code, etc.).

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: Still seems like a lot of memory usage (and probably a ton of setup time) to use that crazy dictionary structure, but I'll leave the design question aside and focus on the main question at hand. If you're not using `.Exists` or `.Keys` then you can probably get away with the `Collection` object instead of using `Dictionary`. It's actually faster in almost every situation, but is more barebones, so you'll have to assess what features you need. But if you do a lookup into a `Collection` and it has no entry, it throws an error as desired.

Comment: Interesting. Does Excel automatically remove the Collection from the memory when the sub ends?

Comment: Yes, VBA has garbage collection implemented (I think) via reference counting. So when the last living reference to your `Collection` goes out of scope, the `Collection` gets deallocated. This will naturally happen at the end of a Sub unless you've retained a reference to the `Collection` somewhere else still in scope (e.g. as a part of a calling Sub or member of another object that still has a reference). You can also manually delete the current reference via `Set myCollection = Nothing` (though again, it won't be deleted until all references to it go out of scope).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a function to "wrap" your top-level dictionary so you can call it with the three "keys" and get back an error value if that combination doesn't exist.

```
Function DoFactorLookup(k1, k2, k3) As Variant
    Dim d, d2, rv

    rv = CVErr(xlErrNA) ' #N/A error value

    If FactorLookup.exists(k1) Then
        Set d = FactorLookup(k1)
        If d.exists(k2) Then
            Set d2 = d(k2)
            If d2.exists(k3) Then
                rv = d2(k3)
            End If
        End If
    End If

    DoFactorLookup = rv
End Function
```

Comment: I ended up taking this approach. Thanks for the help.